# Lost my iOS 5 debug symbols. How do I get them back?

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, ios5, xcode4.2

I just upgraded Xcode to the latest (4.2 (4C199)) and my iPhone to iOS 5(9A334). I'm using Snow Leopard. While debugging, I noticed I don't get any information with my stack trace. It's just a list of addresses, there's no class or method information.

I figured maybe it was switching to LLDB, so I switched back to GDB. Nope, still a problem.

I hooked up an iPad running iOS 5, but a different version, one of the betas (9A5313e), and still an issue.

Then I hooked up an iPad 2 running iOS 4.3.5. Bam! A useful stack trace. So I went looking into the bowels of the /Developer folder, specifically into /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport, like links on Google told me to, but the things I've tried aren't working.

How do I get symbols so my stack traces work in iOS 5?

Comment: I seem to be having exactly the same problem... When I use profiler I also can't see any of my apps own symbols.. is this the same for you?

Comment: I think you might have a different problem: the profiler, by default, runs the app in release, which may strip symbols depending on your configuration. This is all pretty advanced iOS development stuff, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841610/xcode-4-2-debug-doesnt-symbolicate-stack-call

Comment: @Thomas - make that an answer and it's yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841610/xcode-4-2-debug-doesnt-symbolicate-stack-call) deals with the same issue and has a straightforward workaround.

Apple seems to still have some issues to iron out with the latest XCode / iOS 5 combination.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running the App from xCode in debug mode and not in a different configuration (release) ?

Go to Product-->Edit Scheme and verify the  configuration for Run and Archive!
Make sure it's not set to "Release"

Comment: I'm running debug configuration. Other OS versions, like 4.3.5, give me stack traces as desired.