# Xcode 4.2 debug doesn't symbolicate stack call

Tags: ios, xcode, debug-symbols

I have a problem with Xcode 4.2 debugging in an iOS 5 simulator/device. The following code crashes, as expected:

```
NSArray *arr=[NSArray array];
[arr objectAtIndex:100];
```

In iOS 4, I get a useful stack trace of hex numbers. But in iOS 5, it just gives me:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16b4052 0x1845d0a 0x16a0674 0x294c 0x6f89d6 0x6f98a6 0x708743 0x7091f8 0x7fcaa9 0x2257fa9 0x16881c5 0x15ed022 0x15eb90a 0x15eadb4 0x15eaccb 0x6f02a7 0x6faa93 0x2889 0x2805)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Nothing I tried would fix this (tried both compilers, both debuggers, etc.)
After upgrading XCode for the iOS 5 update, no stack traces seemed to work.

However, I have found an effective work-around - creating my own exception handler (which is also useful for other reasons). First, create a function that will handle the error and output it to the console (as well as whatever else you want to do with it):

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
    // Internal error reporting
}
```

Next, add the exception handler to your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
    // Normal launch stuff
}
```

That's it!

If this doesn't work, then there are **only two possible reasons**:

1. Something is overwriting your `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` call (there can be only one handler for your entire app). For example, some 3rd party libraries set their own uncaughtExceptionHandler. So, try setting it at the END of your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function (or selectively disabling 3rd party libraries). Or better yet, set a symbolic break point on `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` to quickly see who is calling it. What you may want to do is to modify your current one rather than adding another one.
2. You're not actually encountering an exception (for example, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is **not** an exception; credit to @Erik B's comments, below)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work -- the `uncaughtExceptionHandler` routine is never invoked.

Comment: Very, very nice. BTW to anyone who this may help, if you have an exception breakpoint set also, you will still need to press continue a few times before it prints the stack trace.

Answer (score 111):

There is a useful option of adding an Exception Breakpoint (using the + at the bottom of the Breakpoint Navigator).  This will break on any Exception (or you can set conditions).  I don't know if this choice is new in 4.2 or if I only finally noticed it trying to workaround the missing symbols problem.

Once you hit this breakpoint you can use the Debug Navigator to navigate the call stack, examine variables, etc as usual.

If you do want a symbolicated call stack suitable for copy/pasting or the like, gdb backtrace will work fine from there:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x01f84cf0 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x019efced in -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
```

(etc)

Comment: This used to work for me, but today it stopped working.  XCode halted inside the Cocoa assembly code for objc_exception_throw, but there was nothing useful on the stack (and yes, I had the stack detail slider all the way to the right).  However, Zane's answer above still works for me.  So, if you run into this situation, you can try that.

Answer (score 46):

There is a new feature on the debugger. You can set a break point whenever a exception is thrown and stop the execution right there, just as it used to happen on 4.0.

On the "Breakpoint Navigator", add a "Exception Breakpoint" and just press "Done" on the options popup.

That's all!

PS: In some cases would be better to break only for Objective-C exceptions.

Comment: This was the issue for me.  A colleague and I share the same Xcode project and I asked him if he was having the problem, and he wasn't.  The difference was that his project was breaking on objective-c exceptions  (objc_exception_throw)

Answer (score 21):

Here is one more solution, not so elegant as previous, but if you didn't add exception breakpoints or handlers, it can be only one way to go.
When app crashes, and you get your raw *first throw call stack* (in hex numbers), type into Xcode console `info line *hex` (don't forget star and `0x` hex specifier), for example:

```
(gdb) info line *0x2658
Line 15 of "path/to/file/main.m" starts at address 0x25f2 <main+50>
and ends at 0x267e <main+190>.
```

If you are using **lldb**, you can type `image lookup -a hex` (without star in this situation), and you get similar output.

With this method, you can traverse from top of the throw stack (there will be about 5-7 system  exception propagators) to your function which caused a crash, and determine exact file and line of code.

Also, for similar effect you can use atos utility in terminal, just type:

```
atos -o path/to/AplicationBundle.app/Executable 0xAdress1 0xAdress2 0xAdress3 ...
```

and you get symbolicated stack trace (at least for functions you have debug symbols).
This method is more preferable, because you don't have for each adress call `info line`, just copy adresses from console output and paste them into terminal.

Answer (score 9):

You can add an **Exception Breakpoint** (using the + at the bottom of the Breakpoint Navigator) and **add the action** `bt` to it (click the Add Action button, select Debugger Command, enter "bt" in the text field). This will display the stack trace as soon as an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 6):

This is a common problem, not getting stack traces in 4.2. You can try swapping between LLDB and GDB to see if you get better results.

File a bug report here.

http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

EDIT:

I believe that if you swap back to LLVM GCC 4.2 you'll not see this happen. You may lose features you need though.

Comment: FYI: In this instance, it has nothing to do with the version of the compiler or debugger that you're using. This is a change in the console output from the iOS.

Comment: Interesting how much experiences of this vary - I think there are a few problems. I was not able to get the debugger to stop on the exception breakpoint. Switching from GDB to LLDB solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code in your main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int retVal;
    @try {
        retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
        NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
    }
    @finally {
        [pool release];
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with storyboards.                      2012-06-04 20:34:52.211 Problems[1944:207] The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file.
2012-06-04 20:34:52.213 Problems[1944:207] Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Answer (score 6):

At Xcode's debug console prompt type:

> `image lookup -a 0x1234`

And it will show you something like:

```
  Address: MyApp[0x00018eb0] (MyApp.__TEXT.__text + 91088)
  Summary: MyApp`-[MyViewController viewDidAppear:] + 192 at MyViewController.m:202
```

Answer (score 1):

Turning 'Compile for Thumb' back on (debug configuration) worked for me.