# run error sends me to code I didn't write

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, lldb

Whenever I click a certain button, the app always dies and I'm sent to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    THIS LINE ==> int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

For those who are familiar, you know that I didn't write this code. I don't know how to find out where my error is!

Also, the output shows this:

```
2011-10-27 21:03:17.690 My Program[55441:207] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UITabBarController: 0x68181f0>.
(lldb)
```

I don't know where to look short of commenting out code line by line until I find the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: that's not a bad strategy. Though a better one is to comment out *half* your code so that you can find the error in `log(N)` time.

Comment: Commending out your apps main entry point (the line you've indicated) is not going to get you far. Try setting a breakpoint at the start of the button's method, and stepping through until the crash.

Comment: @Kenny I was planning on commenting out the code related to the button that I push and starting there, not the `main` code (I realize now that I didn't make that clear).

Comment: It's highly likely that you are using XCode 4.2. By the way, can you please paste your code snippet? Are you using that button to present a viewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the button *click* a new `UIView` is pushed into the `Window`. That view's .xib had *linkage* that was bad (linked to an `IBOutlet` that didn't exist in code anymore because it was renamed).

I set up the correct *linkage* in `Interface Builder` and I no longer got the error. I ***wish*** xcode would at least tell you there's a problem with one of your .xib files.

**PART 2**

Shortly after that *fix* I was getting this error **again**. After *searching the web* for a bit, I found that it *could* be related to a ***memory leak*** so I ran the `Project->Analyze` tool. When I fixed `Xcode`'s suggestions, everything ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running the fact that Xcode 4.2 does not show stack traces most of the time. Check this SO post.

[Xcode 4.2 debug doesn't symbolicate stack call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841610/xcode-4-2-debug-doesnt-symbolicate-stack-call)

Comment: I fixed the original issue, then got this "error" again for something else a while after. I tried the solution you sent over, but i'm still sent to `main` - I'll keep looking into it. +1 for your resource.