# Xcode 4.2 showing the wrong line of code on error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode always stopping at main.m after a crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321184/xcode-always-stopping-at-main-m-after-a-crash)

On versions of Xcode in the past, every time I was debugging a crash, it stopped the debugging in the culprit line, with an error message.

Xcode 4.2 instead shows me this line in main.m

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

as the culprit line for the crash, despite the error being in another place.

How do I get this to work in Xcode 4.2 like it used to work in earlier versions?

Comment: I had incorrect debug stops in the past, where they usually ended up in main as it did for you. It usually means that the problem was a memory issue, which only became a problem as the compiler found the screwed up memory--right about where it stopped in main. I'm not sure that it's really a fixable problem.

Comment: Have you set a break point when exceptions are thrown this sometimes drops you to the right line

Comment: thanks, but the old behavior was way better. Xcode 4 is a hyper jump into mediocrity.

Comment: I've had similar problems -- the app will error out, but it won't show the line of code it errors on. This was never an issue before 4.2.

Comment: @Paul.s Thank you I had not done an iphone app in a while and the exception breakpoint was the crucial thing I forgot to do!  In latest xcode just go to breakpoint navigator(command-6) and click + on the bottom. Whoops - this is an endorsed answer below but doesn't come to top for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how to reclaim the old behavior.

Zane Claes offers a great solution on a similar question here.

[Xcode 4.2 debug doesn't symbolicate stack call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841610/xcode-4-2-debug-doesnt-symbolicate-stack-call)

After you find what class your app is crashing in you can use the debugger to step through and find the culprit

Comment: I know the class it is crashing, but Xcode is not stopping there.

Answer (score 11):

Go to the breakpoints panel, and add the bottom left, click the + sign and add an "Exception breakpoint".

Exceptions : All
Break : On throw.

That should solve the problem in most cases.