# Xcode 4.3.2 + iOS SDK 5.1 Exception Breakpoint not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, exception, crash

Having Followed these threads:
- [Xcode always stopping at main.m after a crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321184/xcode-always-stopping-at-main-m-after-a-crash)
- [Xcode 4.2 showing the wrong line of code on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973555/xcode-4-2-showing-the-wrong-line-of-code-on-error)
- [Debugging app crashes with iOS Simulator & XCode 4 halts in main() function, not crash source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000139/debugging-app-crashes-with-ios-simulator-xcode-4-halts-in-main-function-not)

I am still crashing at 'main' as opposed to the actual line of the crash.

- Oddly Works on iOS 4.3 simulator!
- Does not work on iOS 5.1 simulator, or the iOS 5.0 simulator
- I have the exception breakpoint setup and active. (Exception: All, Break: On Throw. Also have tried Break: On Catch)
- Using Apple LLVM 3.1 compiler
- Base SDK 5.1
- Deploy target set to 4.0
- Configuration is set to debug
- Project is ARC enabled
- XCode 4.3

Thanks

Comment: try setting the breakpoint to "On Catch"

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately does not work either :( I'm going to edit my question to reflect this

Comment: I remember that behaviour from another project, and most of the time it were uninitialized objects or use of `obj = value;` instead of `self.obj = value;`. iOS 4 simulator silently ignores those, iOS 5 is more picky it seems. Step thru the code with the debugger or use NSLog() to find out how far you get.

Comment: try adding a few more exception breakpoints: NSKVODeallocBreak, malloc_error_break, exec_bad_access.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, have tried them all and given it some time but still no luck.
The Debugger spits out correct message:
" *** First throw call stack:
(0x223d022...)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)" 

The crash still points to main.

I am purposely causing a crash where I set up an array and try to get an object at an index beyond it's bounds. Even this crash points to main.

Comment: Are you using lldb or gdb to do the debugging? I'm finding that lldb is a bit unstable.

Comment: oh my.... switching to gdb fixed all my woes, including constant crashes every time I set a break point in xcode which was driving me insane... thank you @ThomasW ...Now how should I go about marking this question as resolved? Thanks again!

Comment: ok. i wrote up my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `lldb` is somewhat unstable and appears to be the cause of the crashes in your case. Switching to `gdb` can cause these crashes to go away.

Comment: thanks, 'lldb' seemed to be the cause of much frustation. switching to 'gdb' has resolved my issues!

Comment: So why is lldb the default? :/

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson Apple probably pushed lldb as the default prematurely.

Comment: No, I meant why is it the default now that it's known that it's unstable?

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson I'm not sure if it is still unstable because I have it turned off, but I'll start using it with 4.4.1 and see what it is like now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Breakpoints -> Add -> Add symbolic breakpoint. A new window pops up.

Type "objc_exception_throw" in symbol field and click Done.

Comment: Same here. I'm sorry, XCode 4 debugging leaves a lot wanting when you've used proper IDEs before.