# problems debugging in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, debugging, xcode4

I am writing an iPhone app in Xcode 4.2.1, and I get an error somewhere that causes the app to crash. The only output on the consol is **(gdb)**. I don't even know where to begin fixing because there is no output! Is there a tool I can use to get additional info? I have tried Instruments, and I get nothing.

Help!

Comment: Xcode changed to not stop on exceptions. It is a strange change on their part, this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321184/xcode-always-stopping-at-main-m-after-a-crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get additional information by enabling the NSZombie.

Procedure to enable NSZombie: from top of the screen menu select product>Edit Scheme>Environment variables > prees + button> type NSZombieEnabled in name > in value set YES

Comment: write it helps a lot in finding reason for crash !!