# Exception or Crash breakpoint always goes to main.m

Tags: ios, xcode

I do not understand why the exception breakpoint always goes to `main.m` instead of stopping exactly at the exception in the `ViewController.m` file.

I have tried solutions from the following links, but nothing seems to work:

[Xcode always stopping at main.m after a crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321184/xcode-always-stopping-at-main-m-after-a-crash)

[Xcode exception breakpoint doesn't print details of the exception being thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238673/xcode-exception-breakpoint-doesnt-print-details-of-the-exception-being-thrown)

**My case is simple:** I am trying to return a string from an `NSArray`, but its a `NSDictionary`. This is why the program crashes:

> > [__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000673a40
> >
> > & error description ..

See my settings in the breakpoint navigator:

[image]

> > Even i have enabled zombie state

I want the breakpoint to stop in the `ViewController.m` file where the exception or crash occurs. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Make Exception type from `Objective-C` to `All` and try.

Comment: I have already tried it , not works.

Comment: Your image doesn't show... did you try adding `po $arg1` as the action?

Comment: @DonMag friend i have tried it too, it is printing error log only.

Comment: Can you show very brief code that you are using?

Comment: @DonMag, i know what is the my crash issue, my question is not for why i am getting crash. Please read question one more time.

Comment: Right... I'm asking if you have brief code that causes the crash, so someone else (such as myself) could run a couple tests - *using the exact same code* - to see if we can resolve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139974/discussion-between-yummy-and-donmag).

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 8.3 after adding only "Exception Breakpoint" the breakpoint stops where the exception occurs[image: See screenshot]