# How can I fix this SIGABRT error with my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, sigabrt

I am currently developing an app in Xcode 4 for the IPhone and I have com across this error, "Thread 1: Program Received Signal: SIGABRT", This error is in my main.m code.

```
//
//  main.m
//  MyCard
//
//  Created by Nazar Gren on 2/2/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Nazar Gren. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "mycardAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([mycardAppDelegate         class]));
     }
 }
```

My error appears on the line under the @autorelease pool line. In the debugger, I get this message, "This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger." And this error only occurs when I attempt to debug my app. My app doesn't even run. Can anyone help? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: None of these helped. Can I send my project to any of you via EMail to fix? I am fairly new to Xcode.

Answer (score 8):

If this is happening on the simulator, restart your computer. If this is happening on a real device, restart the device, and if the problem persists, restart the computer as well. This problem has occurred for me multiple times, because of a zombified process left on the device/simulator when a test is unexpectedly aborted. A simple reboot will fix it.

Comment: None of these helped. Can I send my project to any of you via EMail to fix? I am fairly new to Xcode.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with your project. You have rebooted all of the devices involved and not resolved the problem?

Comment: Could you show the solution to the problem that you used so future users with the same problem can be helped?

Comment: Ya, for the error that I got in the debugger, I restarted the mac and it worked.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you should mark it as the solution for future users.

Comment: I restarted my computer its still not working

Comment: This didn't work for me but worth a try for others I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

All your code gets run through the `main.m`. So what you really want to see is a *stack trace* and there's is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841610/xcode-4-2-debug-doesnt-symbolicate-stack-call), but I see you're using the autoreleasepool so you'll need something like

```
//
//  main.m
//  MyCard
//
//  Created by Nazar Gren on 2/2/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Nazar Gren. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "mycardAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     @autoreleasepool {
        @try {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([mycardAppDelegate class]));
        } @catch (NSException *e) {
            NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", e);
            NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [e callStackSymbols]);
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: None of these helped. Can I send my project to any of you via EMail to fix? I am fairly new to Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

This is not in Main code. Can be anywhere. Please try zombie tool in instruments. You are probably trying to access an object which has been already released. NSZombie will tell you which is the object and you can investigate from there.

Comment: None of these helped. Can I send my project to any of you via EMail to fix? I am fairly new to Xcode.

Comment: @user1186514, how did you fixed your issue (Signal Sigabart), i am also facing same issue in my app, i tried somany ways, but i dint figuredout, could you please suggest me how you had handle that issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove a reference to something attached in your main storyboard?

If so, checkout the referencing outlets of that object to see if it's still trying to point to something, try removing that reference and running your simulator again...