# NSInvalidArgumentException: "Invalid Region" in MapKit app

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-maps, mapkit

I'm trying to set all latitudes and longitudes as coming from local database in google map with dropping annotations at there.The required values of lat and long come after clicking a button and on the next screen,there is another button which on clicking produce the same result.Luckily, I'm able to refresh the map with new annotations, but as I'm trying to go back the ipad app on device get crash with following crash message:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region '
*** First throw call stack:
(0x382178bf 0x37d631e5 0x382175f5 0x3365539b 0x6b26b 0x6e6a7 0x64c81 0x63753 0x6a84d 0x38171435 0x31cda9eb 0x31cda9a7 0x31cda985 0x31cda6f5 0x31cdb02d 0x31cd950f 0x31cd8f01 0x31cbf4ed 0x31cbed2d 0x37f45df3 0x381eb553 0x381eb4f5 0x381ea343 0x3816d4dd 0x3816d3a5 0x37f44fcd 0x31ced743 0x355b 0x2fa4)

But, working well on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using XCode 4, which has a known problem with not showing the crashlog stack properly. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841610/xcode-4-2-debug-doesnt-symbolicate-stack-call/7896769#7896769) to enable showing the stack trace when you get an exception and then please resubmit the crash again. It may not be possible to help you with this issue without a proper exception stack.

Comment: Hi Amiramix,                                                                    Thanks for your quick response, and I'll surely follow your link.But, as today I tried to seek the root of this cause, I found following...

Comment: The crash is coming due to zooming of map-view.As,I've maintained the provision of depicting the map-view altogether with the table view in left half,but on appearing of that screen,the map-view zooming is too much.Please guide me how could I set it as I've already tried to minimize it by setting different span values started from 0.001 to 32.001.Also, I'm setting the multiple annotations at viewWillAppear as I've to constantly need to changing the annotations point as per different cases.Please do your need-full help.Please accept my thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the crashlog and also a snippet of your code that is causing the problem (if possible).

Comment: Hi Amiramix, Thanks for your needful help, but the above problem is sorted-out by making the provision of setting the region dynamically. Later, will paste my code here so to assist other developers in future.