# Strange UISearchDisplayController Crash with hidden keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a IUSearchBar with an UISearchDisplayController, and everything is working well:

- When I touch the search bar, the keyboard shows up, the TableView has a black cover on it and I can start typing

[screenshot 1 http://joeranbosma.nl/xcode/sdc1.png](http://joeranbosma.nl/xcode/sdc1.png)

- When I type something the clear button (x) appears, and so do my search results.

[screenshot 1 http://joeranbosma.nl/xcode/sdc2.png](http://joeranbosma.nl/xcode/sdc2.png)

- This works all great. When I click on the clear (x) button, it just returns to the first screenshot state (empty search bar, and a black box above the results)

**But, here it comes!**

- When I type something and then move the search result, the keyboard hides (standard UISearchDisplayController thing)
  Like this:

[screenshot 1 http://joeranbosma.nl/xcode/sdc3.png](http://joeranbosma.nl/xcode/sdc3.png)

When I **then** click on the clear (x) button, the program crashes with a SIGABRT error:

[screenshot 1 http://joeranbosma.nl/xcode/sdc4.png](http://joeranbosma.nl/xcode/sdc4.png)

.. and I have no idea how to fix this :(

Here is my source code: (no idea what you need to solve the question)
http://joeranbosma.nl/xcode/wearch_stack.zip

But I think this is the most useful part:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Initialize the array.
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    copyListOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    staticlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    staticlist = listOfItems;

    //Add items
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Iceland"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Greenland"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Switzerland"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Norway"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"New Zealand"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Greece"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Rome"];
    [listOfItems addObject:@"Ireland"];

    //Set the title
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Wearch";

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return 1;
}
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (searching)
        return [copyListOfItems count];
    else {
        return [listOfItems count];
    }
}
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    if(searching)
        cell.textLabel.text = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else {
        NSString *txtLbl = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [txtLbl stringByAppendingString:@"x"];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Get the selected word

    NSString *selectedWord = nil;

    if(searching)
        selectedWord = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else {
        selectedWord = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    //Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.selectedWord = selectedWord;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;  
}
- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    searching = YES;
}
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    //Remove all objects first.
    [copyListOfItems removeAllObjects];

    if([searchText length] > 0) {
        searching = YES;
        [self searchTableView];
    }
    else {
        searching = NO;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    [self searchTableView];
}
- (void) searchTableView {

    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *results1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *results2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:listOfItems];

    for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray) {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0){
            if (titleResultsRange.location == 0) {
                [results1 addObject:sTemp];
            }
            else{
                [results2 addObject:sTemp];
            }
        }
    }

    for (NSString *sTemp in results1) {
        [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
    }
    for (NSString *sTemp in results2) {
        [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
    }

    [searchArray release];
    searchArray = nil;
}
```

I hope one of you can solve this.

Can you also say if you like the images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting one. The long answer is that `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:` is being called after `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` but before `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. The result is that the `tableView` is expecting `[listOfItems count]` number of rows but by the time it calls `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the `searching` BOOL is `YES` so the view controller uses `copyListOfItems` to populate the table which of course does not contain a sufficient number of objects to populate the table.

The short answer is, stop telling the view controller you are searching until you are searching; Set `searching = YES;` when there is actual text you are using to search not just when the `searchBar` is first responder.

The really short answer:

```
- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    // Comment this assignment out
    //searching = YES;
}
```

It seems to work fine.

**A couple of tips for such a scenario:**

1) Look at the printed stacktrace in your console. It would have let you see that the problem was:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

2) Use `NSLog`s profusely; I find the most helpful to be:

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

**Edit** In response to the non-symbolicated stack-trace in the console(i.e. `0x14d3ec9 0x36e5c2`):

3) Use an exception breakpoint; as pictured:

[image]

4) Add an uncaught exception handler; [As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7896769/927947).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!
That was indeed the problem. 
But, besides you found the problem, I understand the language better now. 
And I never looked at the console because the was a lot of this: 

'422af1 0x14d3ec9 0x36e5c2 0x36e55a 0x413b76 0x41403f 0x4132fe 0x393a30 0x393c56 0x37a384 0x36daa9 0x1bc8fa9 0x14a61c5 0x140b022 0x140990a 0x1408db4 0x1408ccb 0x1bc7879 0x1bc793e 0x36ba9b 0x256d 0x24e5)'

And I just didn't knew there was something useful, so I didn't looked further. 
So: thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help, especially someone who wants to learn more. So I added a couple more tips to help with the useless hex stack-trace you mentioned.

Comment: It goes really upward with my app :)