# Is there a way to decode the hex code that comes up with a crash in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, string, crash, hex

Is there a way to decode the hex code that comes up with a crash in Xcode?  I have looked online for hex converters and it just pulls up gibberish.  Like, I got a hex code error that reads:

> (0x3901f56b 0x32f1997f 0x3901f261 0x355a906d 0x35dfe1f9 0x35582e9b 0x38f76c63 0x35ea7fe1 0x35e29607 0x35d07821 0x35e298a1 0x35e2d56f 0x35d241f3 0x35d23691 0x283e17b 0x5e8a7 0x35cf7a1d 0x35d68de9 0x356218bf 0x38ff009f 0x38fefd51 0x38fee939 0x38f6cc1d 0x38f6caa9 0x3918633b 0x35c7b535 0x4bbb1 0x4b860)

I went to a hex-string converter and it gave me this:

> ??V°?/—ð?&?U©Ð?]þ?U‚é°?vÆ0?^§þ?^)`p?]‚?^)Š?^-Vð?]$0?]#i?ƒá{?^Šp?\÷¡Ð?]hÞ?V!‹ð?ð    ð?ïÕ?î“?lÁÐ?lª?‘†3°?{SP?»±?K†?

I also looked at my code as hex and those characters did not come up in the code anywhere.  Is there a way to decode this, or is it just computer nonsense that is not supposed to make any sense to humans?

Comment: Those look like memory addresses, in which case there's nothing to decode.

Comment: Is it a IDE Crash? or just your program that crashed at execution??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking at but that's probably a stack dump. (In which case it makes no sense to try to convert it to ASCII.)

Comment: Refer to this answer for what may seem like a good answer to your question, as long as the IDE is not crashing, maybe you can catch this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841610/xcode-4-2-debug-doesnt-symbolicate-stack-call

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible to decode somehow, so thanks for the info